# setOnItemClickListener not getting called

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I have this in the onCreate method as follows:

```
    ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
   adapter = new ModuleAdapter(this);
   lv.setAdapter(adapter);
   lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Then later in the code:

```
    @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.v(TAG, "clicked");

}
```

OnItemClickListener is being implemented.

I'm trying to fire a new activity from onItemClick but it does not appear to be working.

New to Android and don't know a lot of java. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Try to change android.R.id.list with R.id.list and tell me if its still not working.

Comment: I get "list cannot be resolved or is not a field" when I change to R.id.list

Comment: I've nothing showing in logcat when I click on a row.

Answer (score 0):

```
ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

It's if you trying to get android System resources, but you want listview which you describe on xml layout.

Let's say it's look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

so you need change your code to

ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

Some explain:

- `android.R` - it's default resources of Android OS - llike
  buttons,images, listview items layouts and etc.
- `R` - it' your project resoures full path likes [your package path].R
  for example: com.example.R

Comment: Thanks I originally had android:id="@android:id/list" but I've changed it to @+id/list but this crashes the application. Head fried, may have to look at this tomorrow. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've amended my code as you've suggested. I'm still getting absolutely no reaction from a click event. Is there any other clues from my code as to what may be causing this? My rows contain only text fields, though I've tried setting focusable and clickable to false as suggested from other stack overflow threads. I'm extending base adapter for my adapter, if this affects anything?

Answer (score 0):

Do you set FocusableInTouchMode to be true in your layout? If so then onItemClick will not be called.

Answer (score 0):

Try this changes in the xxx_row.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:enabled="false">
</TextView>
```

At least for me it worked when i changed the width and enabled attributes.

Comment: Hi, I found the solution to this problem months ago and posted the solution. It appears to have been deleted by the powers that be, for reasons best know to themselves. It was correct though.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if what you are trying to do is intentional. You are setting click listener on the whole list view container. I believe you wanted to set a click listener for the items inside. I will give you an example below, but also please note that I am extending RecyclerView here instead of using ListView which is rather obsolete.

Java version:

```
public class ModuleAdapter2 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ModuleAdapter2.ItemViewHolder> {

private final List<Item> items;
private final ModuleAdapterListener listener;

public ModuleAdapter2(List<Item> items, ModuleAdapterListener listener) {
    this.items = items;
    this.listener = listener;
}

public static class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ItemModuleBinding binding;

    public ItemViewHolder(ItemModuleBinding binding) {
        super(binding.getRoot());
        this.binding = binding;
    }
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)  {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    ItemModuleBinding binding = ItemModuleBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false);
    return new ItemViewHolder(binding);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Item item = items.get(position);
    holder.binding.getRoot().setOnClickListener(v -> listener.onItemClicked(item));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}

interface ModuleAdapterListener {
    void onItemClicked(Item item);
}}
```

Kotlin version:

```
class ModuleAdapter(var items: MutableList<Item>, private val listener: ModuleAdapterListener) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ModuleAdapter.ItemViewHolder>() {

inner class ItemViewHolder(val binding: ItemModuleBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ItemViewHolder {
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val binding = ItemModuleBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false)
    return ItemViewHolder(binding)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.binding.root.setOnClickListener {
        listener.onItemClicked(items[position])
    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return items.size
}

interface ModuleAdapterListener {
    fun onItemClicked(item: Item)
}}
```

If by any chance you wanted to use the click listener for the container, the reason why it is not working for you, is that the container is consuming the click within the onTouch method (and that is why you are not getting your onClick events). If you would like to overcome this, find some good solutions in both Java and Kotlin here: [setOnClickListener for recyclerView not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45298603/setonclicklistener-for-recyclerview-not-working)