# setOnItemClickListener not responding

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [setOnItemClickListener not getting called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201363/setonitemclicklistener-not-getting-called)

I have a custom adapter which extends base adapter. When I set setOnItemClickListener in onCreate and implement onItemClick I'm getting no response when I click on a row.

```
     ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
     adapter = new ModuleAdapter(this);
     lv.setAdapter(adapter);
     lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

after onCreate:

```
     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {

   Log.v(TAG, "clicked");

     }
```

There are only text views in my rows. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use

> lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);

you must implement OnItemClick listener to your Activity.

and also you can use @user1597833 's answer.

if you want to click textview not cell, try @jeet 's answer.

Comment: Found the root of this problem. onWindowFocusChanged (see link to other thread) was gaining focus. Thank you to everyone who responded. [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209429/setonitemclicklistener-not-responding[link]

Answer (score 0):

It seems views in the row item view, has focusable and clickable property true, so child of item take click event, instead of list row item, if it is the case, to solve this issue, change all view's of row item's focusable, and clickable property to false.

Comment: Thanks I've being trying this already, using:android:focusable="false"
  android:clickable="false" does nothing though.

Comment: please paste your activity and adapter's full code.

Comment: can't seem to add more code to this thread as I'm a new user or something. starting new thread.

Comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209919/setonitemclicklistener-not-responding-with-base-adapter[link]