# Debugging a setOnItemClickListener not functioning

Tags: android, onitemclicklistener

I have a `setOnItemClickListener` which isn't being called and I can't figure out why.

The code is part of an online course and its functioning solution code can be found [here](https://github.com/udacity/ud839_Miwok/blob/c2a89bc69a3af9e8aa6d37f1fdaa16e3f6dc4514/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/miwok/NumbersActivity.java). The specific part of the code I'm having trouble with is in NumbersActivity.java and is

```
// Set a click listener to play the audio when the list item is clicked on
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                // Release the media player if it currently exists because we are about to
                // play a different sound file
                releaseMediaPlayer();

                // Get the {@link Word} object at the given position the user clicked on
                Word word = words.get(position);

                // Create and setup the {@link MediaPlayer} for the audio resource associated
                // with the current word
                mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(NumbersActivity.this, word.getAudioResourceId());

                // Start the audio file
                mMediaPlayer.start();

                // Setup a listener on the media player, so that we can stop and release the
                // media player once the sound has finished playing.
                mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mCompletionListener);
            }
        });
```

That app (referred to above) has the desired behavior of playing an audio file when a list item is clicked but mine does not.

I've even tried replacing the whole in my version of the NumbersActivity.java with the functioning one of the app to see if it'd work (to try and localize the bug) with no success. Logging inside the `setOnItemClickListener` is useless since it doesn't get called (my code is exactly the same as the one posted above).

I've read other answers here ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209429/setonitemclicklistener-not-responding) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201363/setonitemclicklistener-not-getting-called)) but the solutions provided there did not work (my code already has those solutions).

Finally, the structure of the `raw` dir is exactly the same in my app and the "solution code" app (thought it could be related to not find the resource when creating the list item objects).

I don't know what's wrong or other ways of debugging this so if anyone has an idea I'd really appreciate it!

content_list.xml

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/root_list_view"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.miwok.NumbersActivity" />
```

single_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="88dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/numbers_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />


    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/single_view"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/numbers_image">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_miwok"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_english"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/play_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Nothing"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT: Adding answers to comments.

1) The course uses ListView for educational purposes, RecyclerView gets introduced later on. The solution code uses ListView and it works though.

2) Added the XML.

3) The Activity code atm is copy-pasted from the link in the beginning of the question.

Comment: how old is this course? You might want to use recyclerView instead of listView

Comment: @TimCastelijns i dont think that can be the issue , as `listView` also can be used now depending on the `UseCase`

Comment: @AbdulKawee there is no reason to use a LV over a RV

Comment: post your xml plz

Comment: Can you please add your activity code

Comment: @TimCastelijns have a loot at this video 2:30 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NqNR3inViNQ&pbjreload=10

Comment: @AbdulKawee arguments made based on the situation in 2016 don't really count anymore

Comment: @TimCastelijns so can you tell us why should we not use LV in simple conditions?

Comment: @AbdulKawee if you have a question just google it. This has been discussed 2452983786347690278396 times already

Comment: Added answers to the questions to the post.