# setOnClickListener for recyclerView not working

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-recyclerview, android-view

For `RecyclerView` if it has not any item, then click on `RecyclerView` works,
but if it has items clicking on `RecyclerView` doesn't work.
Be careful I mean click on just `RecyclerView` not `RecyclerView`'s item

```
recyclerView.setOnClickListener(view -> {Timber.d("recyclerView clicked");});
```

How I can set `RecyclerView` clickable even it has items on it.

Comment: you mean click on particular recycler view row??

Comment: @sumit, no, I mean just the recyclerView not it`s items and rows .
like any other views on i want set click listener on recyclerView

Comment: @MehrdadFaraji place that recycler view in any layout put click listner to that layout if u touch the recycler view it will fire.

Comment: @YBDevi , It's actually in another view , but that's not work so!

Comment: then only u can use OnTouchListener only because if u click on recycler view it will only consider as item click.

Comment: if u want any other thing then place any layout above(both views parent will be relative layout) the recyclerview then make it as invisible and write click listener for that.I don't know it is work r not it is just idea i get.So i am sharing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but if it has items clicking on RecyclerView doesn't work

Why do you think that you are performing a click on the `RecyclerView` itself?
Most possibly the item of the `RecyclerView` swallows the touch event, thus it won't be reached to the `RecyclerView`. You can make the children of `RecyclerView` to be not clickable, then the next item that would be given a chance to respond to click event would be the `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Tried by setting clickable and focusable false for item xml but it didn't help to provide click event to RecyclerView to perform as a View.

Answer (score 5):

Try to extend `RecyclerView` and Override `onInterceptTouchEvent`. Also make it always return **true**. Then use `OnTouch` instead of `OnClickListener`
Here are some of code.

```
public class MyRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {
    public MyRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Activity.class

```
recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"RecyclerView",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yep ,thanks I think this can be work , but I looking for another solution

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR Java**

```
recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
            return view.performClick();
        else
            return false;
    }
});

recyclerView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

**TL;DR Kotlin**

```
recyclerView.setOnTouchListener { view, motionEvent ->
    if (motionEvent.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        view.performClick()
    else
        false
}

recyclerView.setOnClickListener { view ->
    // do something
}
```

**Explanation (Java)**

When the user touches the screen, the `OnTouchListener` of the topmost view is triggered. Its purpose is to detect gestures (tap, long tap, swipe, etc.) and call the respective handlers. A simple tap, for example, should result in a call to the `OnClickListener`.

Now, for some reason, `RecyclerView` does not do that (at least it does not watch for the tap gesture) - maybe because the developers did not intend the `RecyclerView` to be tapped as a whole.

So, we implement the `OnTouchListener` ourselves. The easiest way would be implementing the click logic in the `OnTouchListener` itself and return `true` to keep the event from propagating further up in the view hierarchy:

```
recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        // do something
        return true
    }
});
```

However, as the `OnTouchListener` is usually invoked multiple times during a single tap on the screen, we should run our code only once after the last touch event. Furthermore, the business logic should go into the `OnClickListener` which is called by `performClick()` (that returns `true` afterwards):

```
recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
            return view.performClick();
        else
            return false;
    }
});

recyclerView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use `setOnTouchListener` instead of `setOnClickListener`.

It works for me . . .

```
recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                //Do anyThing you need
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: the interesting thing about this solution is that MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN is never invoked and thus ACTION_UP is invoked if an ACTION_MOVE event has occured

Answer (score 0):

Because nobody had answered the actual question itself yet..

My solution was to put a empty View on top of the RecyclerView withing ConstraintLayout such as

```
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

    <View
            android:id="@+id/touch_overlay"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/recycler_view"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/recycler_view"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/recycler_view"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/recycler_view"/>
```

then I would set the onClickListener on the touch_overlay and it would work as expected.

On the Java/Kotlin side its as expected

```
    binding.touchOverlay.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(context, "clicked recyclerView", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
```

On the other hand, more lightweight solution, especially when not using ConstraintLayout is to use a FrameLayout, then place an empty View on top of the RecyclerView that would receive the clicks

Answer (score 0):

this code works:

```
  recycle.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
                if(event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    onClickListener.onClick(v)
                }
                false
            }
```